# form_dropdown codeigniter when change value select form another form_dropdown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm having an issue when I try to exchange value `form_dropdown2` depend `form_dropdown1`

I don't know how to get `$data['dropdown_lang']` because it returns an array.

What am I doing wrong?

**My code:**

```
class Model_catecontent extends CI_Model {
    function dropdown($parawhere=NULL){
        $data = $this->db->select('cate_id,title')->from('utt_cate_content')->where('lang',$parawhere)->get()->result_array();
        if(isset($data)&&count($data)){
            foreach($data as $key =>$value){
                $list[$value['cate_id']]=$value['title'];
            }
            return $list;
        }
    }
}
```

**Model_lang:**

```
class Model_lang extends CI_Model {
    function dropdown(){
        $data = $this->db->select('code,name')->from('utt_lang')->get()->result_array();
        if(isset($data)&&count($data)){
            foreach($data as $key =>$value){
                $list[$value['code']]=$value['name'];
            }
            return $list;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
$data['dropdown_lang']=$this->Model_lang->dropdown();
$data['dropdown_catecontent']=$this->Model_catecontent->dropdown($data['dropdown_lang']);

<?php echo form_dropdown('cate_id', $dropdown_catecontent, NULL, '');?>
<?php echo form_dropdown('code', $dropdown_lang, 1, '');?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in controller you are calling function dropdown of model_catecontent and that function require a parameter but you are sending an array of $data['dropdown_lang'], it is issue. you need to send a dropdown_lang to that function instead of whole lang array.

Comment: I think using ajax is easy way to do it.And it's working, tks